# Hide an import line when run flutter application in web

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to run my flutter application in both mobile and web.I am implementing Mqtt.So for web
"import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_browser_client.dart'" this import will work and in mobile
'import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart' is work.But when i run the application in mobile after adding 'import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_browser_client.dart' i got
Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:html';
^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:html' is imported through these packages:

So any ways to add the import function based on condition like
if(kIsWeb)package:mqtt_client/mqtt_browser_client.dart else package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally import the correct package using the following syntax:

```
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart' if (dart.library.js) 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_browser_client.dart';
```